# Error trying to start zookeeper server- Confluent setup

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I am trying to setup Confluent-4.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. To start the ZooKeeper server, I ran `./bin/zookeeper-server-start ./etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties.txt` from the root directory of Confluent by following this [tutorial](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-from-command-line/index.html).
The error that comes up is-

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:./bin/../config/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./bin/../config/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:557)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.<clinit>(QuorumPeerMain.java:64)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [file:./bin/../config/log4j.properties].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I am new to kafka, and I have no clue what this means. Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: File `./bin/../config/log4j.properties` was not found.

Comment: @V.G. That file is in `./bin/../etc/kafka/log4j.properties.txt` What do you suggest?

Comment: @leovaldez, 1) According to the tutorial you linked, the command to start Zookeeper is `kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh kafka/config/zookeeper.properties`, where did you get your `./bin/zookeeper-server-start ./etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties.txt` command from? 2) Why is your property file end with .txt? 3) Provide the content of your `/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties.txt` file

Comment: None of those files end with `.txt`... Also, I suggest you use 4.1.2 release instead. As well as Debian Confluent Repo, not the targz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you're following is only Apache Kafka, not Confluent, though they should work similarly at least for starting Zookeeper.

If you've downloaded the Confluent distribution, though, and want a single node cluster, you can use the [Confluent CLI](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/dev-cli.html)

To start Zookeeper, Kafka, and the rest of the Confluent Platform, run

```
./bin/confluent start
```

Otherwise, the Zookeeper startup script doesn't use a txt file, and it might be unable to detect where you've extracted the tarball, so instead you can use apt like a normal software package

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation in the [link](https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/command-reference/local/services/confluent_local_services_start.html)

1:run these commands after changing path-to-confluent with your path
export CONFLUENT_HOME=
export PATH="${CONFLUENT_HOME}/bin:$PATH"
(these commands will make the "confluent" command recognizable from
terminal)

2: run below command
confluent local services start
(this command will start all the services including zookeeper ,
kafka, schema registry etc)